# Need to download all documents from CRM 2011 to a local folder

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to download all documents from CRM 2011 (from every notes and email, basically I need each and every document) along with to a local windows folder.

Is there a custom C# code or powershell script to do this?

Kindly let me know if there are any open source tool or paid tools for doing this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple piece of code to do this. Please see [Exporting Annotation (Note) Attachment](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/exporting-annotation-note-attachment/).

```
public void ExportDocuments(IOrganizationService service, String filePath)
{
     String fetch = @"<fetch mapping='logical' count='100' version='1.0'>
          <entity name='annotation'>
               <attribute name='filename' />
               <attribute name='documentbody' />
               <attribute name='mimetype' />
          </entity>
     </fetch>";

     foreach (Entity e in service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch)))
     {
          if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString()))
          {
               byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());

               File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + e.Attributes["filename"].ToString(), data);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: In case of doc file, it works only for those doc files which uploaded manually, It does not work for the doc which got generated using OOB document generation and attached in any entity. It downloads the corrupted word document file type.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @ACRM, post a new question